# VBA: Display the min, max, avg using an Excel WorksheetFunction excluding canceled and no shows

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use the Excel Worksheet Function to find and display the maximum, minimum, and average for all procedures. I need to exclude the data that is listed as "canceled" or "no show" and only show the min, max, and avg for data listed as "treated". I need to do these functions inside of a for loop using If statement.  I tried creating an array that would tell my code not to use those values but I am getting errors of type mismatch in the highlighted line. I believe there is a simple way to do this but I can't seem to get it right. Check out my code starting at Step 3.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z9jZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z9jZ.png)

```
 Range("E2:E447").Name = "ProcTime"
'Step 2: Compute and display the minimum, the maximum, and the average for             
        all procedures
     Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("E"))
     Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns("E"))
     Avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Columns("E"))
         MsgBox ("The minimum is " & Min & " The maximum is " & Max & " The 
                 average is " & Avg)
'Step 3: Repeat Step2, excluding the canceled and no shows
    not_use = Array(Canceled, NoShow) 'Create an array
    use = Array(treated)
    For i = 0 To 447
        If Range("G2").Offset(i, 0).Value = use Then
            Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("E"))
            Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns("E"))
            Avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Columns("E"))
                MsgBox ("The minimum is " & Min & " The maximum is " & Max 
                         & " The average is " & Avg)
    End If
        If IsError(Application.Match(i, not_use, 0)) Then
    End If
   Next
  End With
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52238635/edit) your question with your actual code, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: What's wrong with worksheet formulas?

Comment: @Jeeped When I run the code, it gets a type mismatch on the If range ("G2").offset(i,).value = use line. (Under step 3)

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your code, not an image of your code.

Comment: You might also want to include what version of excel you are using.

Comment: I entered the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use VBA for that. 
You can just use array function (for max and min) within the sheet.

`=MAX(IF(I3:I12="show",B3:B12,0))` array function

`=MIN(IF(I3:I12="show",D3:D12,9.99999999999999))` array function

`=AVERAGEIF(I3:I12,"=show",F3:F12)` normal function

or this

`=AVERAGEIFS(F3:F12,I3:I12,"<>no show",I3:I12,"<>canceled")`

For array function press "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" after you write/paste them in the box.
Excel will put them between {}.

https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula

https://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html

---

There you have a code which will put those formulas to the cells. There is also an example how to use these functions with VBA if you want to assign those values to variables.

```
Sub JustCode()

Dim Max As Double
Dim Min As Double
Dim Avg As Double
Dim Formula As String

Cells(14, 2).FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(I3:I12=""show"",B3:B12,0))"
Cells(14, 4).FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF(I3:I12=""show"",D3:D12,9.99999999999999))"
Cells(14, 6).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(I3:I12,""=show"",F3:F12)"

Debug.Print Cells(14, 2).FormulaArray
Debug.Print Cells(14, 4).FormulaArray
Debug.Print Cells(14, 6).FormulaArray

Max = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=MAX(IF(I3:I12=""show"",B3:B12,0))")
Min = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=MIN(IF(I3:I12=""show"",D3:D12,9.99999999999999))")
Avg = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=AVERAGEIF(I3:I12,""=show"",F3:F12)")

Debug.Print Max
Debug.Print Min
Debug.Print Avg


End Sub
```

It will be probably better to replace ActiveSheet with e.g. Worksheets(1) or Worksheets("some name").

[image: Worksheet]